# iterating over a growing set in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, iteration

I have a set, setOfManyElements, which contains n elements. I need to go through all those elements and run a function on each element of S:

```
for s in setOfManyElements:
   elementsFound=EvilFunction(s)
   setOfManyElements|=elementsFound
```

EvilFunction(s) returns the set of elements it has found. Some of them will already be in S, some will be new, and some will be in S and will have already been tested.

The problem is that each time I run EvilFunction, S will expand (until a maximum set, at which point it will stop growing). So I am essentially iterating over a growing set. Also EvilFunction takes a long time to compute, so you do not want to run it twice on the same data.

Is there an efficient way to approach this problem in Python 2.7?

LATE EDIT: changed the name of the variables to make them more understandable. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Do you have some control over `EvilFunction`? Can you make it return the elements that were added to the set? And how large is that set? Could you keep another set of visited elements?

Comment: indeed I write also EvilFunction I just tried to keep the question as simplified as possible, but you are right, EvilFunction in fact returns the elements it has found, some of which will be new

Comment: Your question is unclear you need to prepare more information about your problem if you want to get a desire answer , you can add a sample input and expected out put and add the code of your function

Comment: A set is just an unordered collection of unique elements. I think that since there is no order of the element you cannot guarantee that the element add by EvilFunction will be inserted after the one you have already visited.

I would iterate over the initial set and return from EvilFunction the list of item that are actually add to the set and keep them into a second set. 
Then you compare the 2 sets and if there is no element in the second that was not already in the first one you are done otherwise you have to iterate over those elements.

Comment: Your names are a little confusing, as it's not easy to see the difference between `s` and `S`. BTW, normal variable names should be lower case, names starting with an upper case letter should be used for classes (and all upper case for global constants).

Comment: You say that  "EvilFunction(s) returns the set of elements it has found." But your code doesn't save the returned object from  `EvilFunction(s)`. Does `EvilFunction(s)` modify the contents of little `s` or of big `S`? In general, you should not modify a container that you're iterating over. If you're careful it _can_ work, but it makes code harder to read and debug.

Comment: That's why I am asking here how to handle it. :-)

Comment: Ok, I change the names

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest an incremental version of 6502's approach:

```
seen   = set(initial_items)
active = set(initial_items)

while active:
    next_active = set()
    for item in active:
        for result in evil_func(item):
            if result not in seen:
                seen.add(result)
                next_active.add(result)
    active = next_active
```

This visits each item only once, and when finished `seen` contains all visited items.

For further research: this is a breadth-first graph search.

Comment: and it is a graph ( a lattice, in particular) so I am not surprised a graph solving function was the one to do the trick. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

You can just keep a set of already visited elements and pick a non-yet-visited element each time

```
visited = set()
todo = S
while todo:
    s = todo.pop()
    visited.add(s)
    todo |= EvilFunction(s) - visited
```

Comment: Thanks. But S-visited can be quite costly, and I would have to run this several times. I am not convinced this is the most efficient and pythonic way. I was thinking along the lines of iterators, but I am not that good with them.

Comment: evil function is slow at the beginning when it is still finding new elements, then it becomes faster :-)

Comment: If the result of `EvilFunction` contains all the added elements (and some more), maybe you could add just those to `todo` and `continue` if the element is in `visited`.

Comment: Yes, but this would require a difference between two sets to be calculated, also quite a costly operation.

Comment: Why are you saying set difference is "costly"? Is it slowing you down? Do you have a profiling result?

Comment: No, on my machine I can't even get out of the first EvilFunction. I am preparing the code to running to the University Big Brother :-).

Answer (score -1):

Iterating a `set` in your scenario is a bad idea, as you have no guarantee on the ordering and the iterator are not intended to be used in a modifying set. So you do not know what will happen to the iterator, nor will you know the position of a newly inserted element

However, using a `list` and a `set` may be a good idea:

```
list_elements = list(set_elements)

for s in list_elements:
  elementsFound=EvilFunction(s)
  new_subset = elementsFound - list_elements
  list_elements.extend(new_subset)
  set_elements |= new_subset
```

---

**Edit**

Depending on the size of everything, you could even drop the `set` entirely

```
for s in list_elements:
  elementsFound=EvilFunction(s)
  list_elements.extend(i for i in elementsFound if i not in list_elements)
```

However, I am not sure on the performance of this. I think that you should profile. If the list is huge, then the `set`-based solution seems good --it is cheap to perform set-based operations. However, for moderate size, maybe the `EvilFunction` is expensive enough and it doesn't matter.